# ValueError: Cannot convert 0 to Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a piece of code that copy/pastes data from Downloaded csv's into a predefined excel template. Some of the csv files have to be transposed before being pasted. This works with no issues on my PC, but on a mac it gives a Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value) error.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    def read_transpose(account_id):


    excel_template = load_workbook('Cost_Optimization_Template.xlsx')

    ec2_utilization = excel_template['EC2 RI Utilization ']
    rds_utilization = excel_template['RDS RI Utilization ']
    elasticity = excel_template['Elasticty']
    ec2_newri = excel_template['EC2 New RI']
    coverage = excel_template['RI Coverage']
    accounts = excel_template['Accounts']   
    services = excel_template['Services']
    spot_by_account = excel_template['Spot Usage by Account']
    spot = excel_template['Spot Usage']
    storage = excel_template['Storage']
    storage_by_account = excel_template['Storage by Account']
    cloudwatch_accounts = excel_template['CloudWatch Accounts']
    instance_types = excel_template['Instance Types']
    ri_graph = excel_template['RI Graph']
    instructions = excel_template['Instructions']

    instructions['C5'] = account_id


    tab_list = [ec2_utilization, rds_utilization, elasticity, ec2_newri, coverage, accounts, services, spot_by_account, spot, storage, storage_by_account, cloudwatch_accounts, instance_types, ri_graph]

    #print excel_template.sheetnames    

    file_list = ['ri-subscriptions.csv', 'ri-subscriptions (1).csv', 'costs.csv', 'ec2-recommendations.csv', 'ri-instanceTypes.csv', 'costs_(1).csv', 'costs_(2).csv', 'costs_(3).csv', 'costs_(4).csv', 'costs (5).csv', 'costs (6).csv', 'costs (7).csv', 'costs (8).csv', 'ri-utilization.csv']

    i = 0
    for file in file_list:

        # catching empty file excpetions in case there is no data to read and/or transpose so this tab needs to be skipped


        print (file)


        wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
        ws = wb.active

        # for transposed files
        if file == 'costs_(1).csv' or file == 'costs_(2).csv' or file == 'costs_(3).csv' or file == 'costs_(4).csv' or file == 'costs_(5).csv' or file == 'costs (6).csv' or file == 'costs (7).csv' or file == 'costs (8).csv':

            df = pd.read_csv(file)
            df = df.transpose()

            print ('hit transpose')

            for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
                ws.append(r)

            ws.delete_rows(1) # necessary to delete the index row that gets created when transposing

        else:

            df = pd.read_csv(file)

            print ('hit non transpose')

            for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
                ws.append(r)
    excel_template.save('cost_optimization_template_{0}.xlsx'.format(account_id))
```

The issue seems to occur only with files that need to be transposed before being pasted as the other ones are actually getting pasted with no issues.

I read through other answers out here but nothing helped solved this issue for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is the full traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cost_optimization.py", line 701, in <module>
    read_transpose('111')
  File "cost_optimization.py", line 612, in read_transpose
    ws.append(r)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 654, in append
    cell = Cell(self, row=row_idx, column=col_idx, value=content)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.value = value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 252, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py", line 218, in _bind_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert 0 to Excel
```

Comment: Are you using the same Python version on both machines to run the code?

Comment: I am yes, using 3.6.3 on my mac and it works on that version on my PC; on the pc it also works on 2.7.1

Comment: I believe that it's transpose() that is causing the error, commenting this line makes it run ok but the data needs to be transposed

Comment: You should include the complete traceback but the issue is most likely related to the version of openpyxl you're using: for performance reasons 2.6 is very fussy about the datatypes it will handle.

Comment: @CharlieClark I just updated the post with the complete traceback, I also tried reinstalling openpyxl using the setup.py from their website but still getting the same error message; Which version would you recommend using? The website only had the latest one

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be the header that got created when transposing, and openpyxl didn't seem to like the 0 in there, changing for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True) to header=False solved it.