# Why will pd.df.to_excel() not work, but importing csv will?

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling to transfer a pandas dataframe to excel.

The error I get is

```
raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert 'ABC1234' to Excel
# ABC1234 is the unique ticket number in the first column of my dataframe.
```

- My research comes up with others who've encountered this when transposing... but I'm not doing that. [ValueError: Cannot convert 0 to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55524770/valueerror-cannot-convert-0-to-excel)
- On the other had `df.to_csv()` works just fine, and I can open the CSV file with excel with no problem at all.
- I have also tried `df.to_excel(filepath, index=False)` if it was maybe to do with headers, but no luck.

df.info() produce this... so I don't see that nulls are a problem.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9893 entries, 0 to 9892
Data columns (total 11 columns):
0     9893 non-null object
1     9893 non-null object
2     9893 non-null object
3     9893 non-null object
4     9893 non-null datetime64[ns]
5     9893 non-null datetime64[ns]
6     9893 non-null object
7     9893 non-null object
8     9893 non-null object
9     9893 non-null object
10    9591 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), object(9)
memory usage: 850.3+ KB
```

I'm wondering where to go from here?

Comment: I think you needed to define 'sep' parameter.

Comment: did you specify the extension ? you need `.xlsx` at the end

Comment: yep, the extension is there - full filename. I'll have a go with the sep paramater... although the docs say it's optional.

Comment: sep paramater? - I can't see it? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html